# cannot access Internet inside docker container when docker0 has non-default address

Tags: docker, networking

Problem: the Internet isn't accessible within a docker container.

on my bare metal Ubuntu 17.10 box...

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=10.8 ms
```

but...

```
$ docker run --rm debian:latest ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
92 bytes from 7911d89db6a4 (192.168.220.2): Destination Host Unreachable
```

I think the root cause is that I had to set up a non-default network for docker0 because the default one `172.17.0.1` was already in use within my organization.

My /etc/docker/daemon.json file needs to look like this in order for docker to start successfully.

```
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
  "bip": "192.168.220.1/24",
  "fixed-cidr": "192.168.220.0/24",
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "0:0:0:0:0:ffff:c0a8:dc00/120",
  "mtu": 1500,
  "default-gateway": "192.168.220.10",
  "default-gateway-v6": "0:0:0:0:0:ffff:c0a8:dc0a",
  "dns": ["10.0.0.69","10.0.0.70","10.1.1.11"],
  "debug": true
}
```

Note that the default-gateway setting looks wrong. However, if I correct it to read `192.168.220.1` the docker service fails to start. Running `dockerd` at the command line directly produces the most helpful logging, thus:

With `"default-gateway": 192.168.220.1` in `daemon.json`...

```
$ sudo dockerd
-----8<-----
many lines removed
----->8-----
Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: failed to allocate secondary ip address (DefaultGatewayIPv4:192.168.220.1): Address already in use
```

Here's the info for docker0...

```
$ ip addr show docker0
10: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:10:bc:66:fd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.220.1/24 brd 192.168.220.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:10ff:febc:66fd/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And routing table...

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.62.131.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp14s0
10.62.131.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp14s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp14s0
192.168.220.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 docker0
```

Is this the root cause? How do I achieve the, seemingly mutually exclusive states of:

- docker0 interface address is x.x.x.1
- gateway address is same, x.x.x.1
- dockerd runs ok

?

Thanks!

Longer answer to Wedge Martin's question. I made the changes to `daemon.json` as you suggested:

```
{
  "bip": "192.168.220.2/24",
  "fixed-cidr": "192.168.220.0/24",
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "0:0:0:0:0:ffff:c0a8:dc00/120",
  "mtu": 1500,
  "default-gateway": "192.168.220.1",
  "default-gateway-v6": "0:0:0:0:0:ffff:c0a8:dc0a",
  "dns": ["10.0.0.69","10.0.0.70","10.1.1.11"],
  "debug": true
}
```

so at least the daemon starts, but I still don't have internet access within a container...

```
$ docker run -it --rm debian:latest bash
root@bd9082bf70a0:/# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: eth0@if16: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:c0:a8:dc:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.220.3/24 brd 192.168.220.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@bd9082bf70a0:/# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
92 bytes from bd9082bf70a0 (192.168.220.3): Destination Host Unreachable
```

Comment: You're not going to be able to set the default gateway to the same IP addr as the container's internal address. Set your bip to .2 or something, and use the default gateway of .1 which probably matches your normal setup.  That route -n looks like it's from your host OS, not the container, correct?

Comment: that's correct - route - n is from the host. The image I'm using doesn't support the route command, or tracert which'd be useful in troubleshooting this.

Comment: if I set the default gateway to .1, and the bip to .10 (which is how I originally had it) dockerd will start, but the Internet isn't accessible from inside a container.

Comment: {
  "bip": "192.168.220.2/24",
  "fixed-cidr": "192.168.220.0/24",
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "0:0:0:0:0:ffff:c0a8:dc00/120",
  "mtu": 1500,
  "default-gateway": "192.168.220.1",
  "default-gateway-v6": "0:0:0:0:0:ffff:c0a8:dc0a",
  "dns": ["10.0.0.69","10.0.0.70","10.1.1.11"],
  "debug": true
}

Comment: You should be able to install some network utilities on the container itself after it's started. I.e. with Alpine images you can do ask add <package name>.  Just ooc, with the setup that should be correct ( .1 and .10 ) can you ping the .1 addr?  Or get an arp response back from it?  arp -n 192.168.220.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that less is more. Simplifying `daemon.json` to the following resolved my issues.

```
{
  "bip": "192.168.220.2/24"
}
```

Comment: It still did not work for me. With this change, docker service comes up but container do not have any network connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set the gw, docker will set it to first non-network address in the network, or .1, but if you set it, docker will conflict when allocating the bridge as the address .1 is in use. You should only set default_gateway if its outside of the network range.

Now the bip can tell docker to use a different address than the .1 and so setting the bip can avoid the conflict, but I am not sure that it will end up doing what you want. Probably will cause routing issues as non-network route will go to address that has no host responding.